# jenkins stopped running deployed on openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift, cluster-computing

im running jenkins on openshift cluster , i installed maven plugin in jenkins and it required a jenkins restart so i checked the " restart after installation " box , and since then it never worked again , it's always unavailable .

[image][image][image][image]

i tried to downscale and upscale the pod , but it's the same issue .